# Kendo How To Change DOM element from JS and how to get changed elements

Tags: kendo-ui, bind

I have 2 connected questions

1-  in kendo ui documentation it says that "When the end-user changes the value of the DOM element (or widget) the bound View-Model value is updated. **If the View-Model value is updated from code the value of the bound DOM element (or widget) is updated visually**."

I couldn't find how the second section (in bold) works. I tried to write

```
devicenoValue = "444444";
```

to check if the DOM element is changing but it didn't work. How can I change it from the javascript side (ofcourse without the standart jquery option)

html code is like below

```
            <li>
                <label>Device No
                    <input type="text" value="" id="device_no"    data-value-update="keyup"  data-bind="value: devicenoValue"/>
                </label>
            </li>
```

JS code is like

> ```
> var settings = kendo.observable({
>
>   devicenoValue: "444444"
> });
>
> kendo.bind($("#device_no"), settings);
> ```

2-   I need to know which element was changed in the DOM. How can I find this? I tried data-value-update="keyup" but couldn't findout how to use it for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part is easy.  You just need to call set on your observable...

```
settings.set("devicenoValue", <yournewValue>);
```

Sample http://jsbin.com/budoh/1/edit

Second part, I am not sure about.  You need a list of DOM elements that were updated when the above set is called on the observable ?